# POST to SESSION variable

Tags: php

On my index page, I have a drop down list that, when clicked, sends the result via POST to the next page. The next page converts one of the POST variables to a SESSION variable. This is the code:

```
      $_SESSION['land']=$_POST['land'];
```

From this page though, I send a POST request to a cart page, which then does the job and goes automatically back to the previous page. The code for this is

```
      header('Location: '.$page);
```

The problem is that when this page goes back to the previous one, the SESSION variable cannot be loaded because there is no POST request. How can I go about making sure no error that comes up?

Any tips and code would be great
Thanks

Comment: It's a task I've been set. I'm just looking for general hints and examples which could help. Thanks.

Comment: How does the page go back to the previous one?  Is this if the user clicks their "Back" button or some control on your page?  Do you want users to be able to use their back button for navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they click a link that takes them back to this page:

```
 if(isset($_POST['land']) && !empty($_POST['land'])){ $_SESSION['land']=$_POST['land']; }
```